# How to use react-router useSubmit hook with input onChange and button onClick events?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to make a search bar with a clear button using the useSubmit hook from react-router. The search query should be submitted both on input change and button click.

SearchBar.tsx

```tsx
import { Form, useSubmit } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ChangeEvent, useState } from 'react';

export default function SearchBar({ query }: { query?: string }) {
  const submit = useSubmit();
  const [q, setQ] = useState(query ?? '');

  function handleChange(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    setQ(event.target.value);
    submitForm(event.currentTarget.form);
  }

  function handleClear(event: any) {
    setQ('');
    submitForm(event.currentTarget.form);
  }

  function submitForm(submitTarget: any) {
    const isFirstSearch = q == null;
    submit(submitTarget, {
      replace: !isFirstSearch,
    });
  }

  return (
    <Form role="search">
      <input
        type="search"
        name="q"
        value={q}
        onChange={handleChange}
        autoComplete="off"
      />
      {q && q.length > 0 && (
        <button type="button" onClick={handleClear}>
          Clear
        </button>
      )}
    </Form>
  );
}
```

todos.tsx

```tsx
import { getTodos } from '../todos';
import { useLoaderData } from 'react-router-dom';
import SearchBar from '../SearchBar';

export async function loader({ request }: { request: Request }) {
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  const q = url.searchParams.get('q');
  const todos = await getTodos(q);
  return { todos, q };
}

export default function Todos() {
  const { todos, q }: any = useLoaderData();

  return (
    <div>
      <SearchBar query={q} />
      <div>
        {todos.length > 0 ? (
          todos.map((todo: any) => <div key={todo.id}>{todo.text}</div>)
        ) : (
          <p>No todos</p>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I click the clear button, the input gets cleared but the submitted query has still the value from before.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-onjxth?file=src/SearchBar.tsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I was able to come up with that worked for the two use cases you describe.

1. Move the calling of `submitForm` to the `Form` component's `onChange` handler to submit the form data when it changes.
2. The `input` element's `onChange` handler only updates the local `q` state and the `value` prop is removed to now be an *uncontrolled* input. We only need the `q` state to conditionally render the "clear" button.
3. The "clear" button should be converted to a `type="submit"` to then also submit the form when clicked.
4. The `handleClear` handler should ***reset*** the form field data.

```
export default function SearchBar({ query }: Props) {
  const submit = useSubmit();
  const [q, setQ] = useState(query ?? '');

  function handleChange(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    setQ(event.target.value);
  }

  function handleClear(event: any) {
    event.currentTarget.form.reset();
  }

  function submitForm(event: any) {
    const isFirstSearch = q == null;
    submit(event.currentTarget, {
      replace: !isFirstSearch,
    });
  }

  return (
    <Form role="search" onChange={submitForm}>
      <input
        type="search"
        name="q"
        onChange={handleChange}
        autoComplete="off"
      />
      {!!q.length && (
        <button type="submit" onClick={handleClear}>
          Clear
        </button>
      )}
    </Form>
  );
}
```

Comment: This works, but the default value from `query` is no longer displayed. I tried `defaultValue={q}` on the input but then the clear button stops working again.

Comment: @M.Schuepbach Yes, I see. The issue with the original code is that React state updates are processed asynchronously, so in the `handleClear` callback the `setQ("")` update hasn't processed yet when `submitForm` is called. This is a bit of a hack, but you could delay the form submission to the end of the event queue using a `setTimeout` call, e.g. `setTimeout(submitForm, 0, event.currentTarget.form);` to allow the `q` state to update and the component to rerender and the form input to have the `""` value when it's submitted. This would be a one-line change to the original code. This make sense?